Error loading model： The service returned the following message: Unexpected zero length CDN resource received, path= undefined,
I am using aps service to render models in the browser. The model has been uploaded and converted successfully. I can see it in the viewer, but an error message appears in the browser, causing some objects to not be displayed.
image error info here
I have tried to re-upload the model and modify the translation parameters, but it didn't work.
return axios({
    url: `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: accessToken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-ads-force': true
    },
    data: {
      input: {
        urn: objectIdURN
      },
      output: {
        formats: [
          {
            type: 'svf2',
            advanced: {
              format: 'binary',
              exportColor: true,
              exportFileStructure: 'single'
            },
            views: ['2d', '3d']
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  })

